# Iterating Through Site Collections in a Tenancy using PnP PowerSHell

Tags: powershell, pnp

Does anyone know how I can Iterate through a series of Site Collections in a Office 365 tenancy using PnP PowerShell ?
I can get a series of Site Collections using :-

```
$sitecollections = Get-PnPTenantSite
```

I now want to iterate through the site collections printing out the title and Url using PnP PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the admin site, the available site collections can be retrieved, using PnP CSOM PowerShell and run the following:

```
$sites = Get-SPOTenantSite -Detailed -IncludeOneDriveSites -Force

Write-Host "There are " $sites.count " site collections present"

foreach($site in $sites){

    Write-Host "Title       : " $site.Title

    Write-Host "URL         : " $site.Url

    Write-Host "Template    : " $site.Template

    Write-Host "Status      : " $site.Status

    Write-Host "Storage (MB): " $site.StorageMaximumLevel

    Write-Host "Used (MB)   : " $site.StorageUsage

    Write-Host "Resources   : " $site.UserCodeMaximumLevel

    Write-Host "Owner       : " $site.Owner

    Write-Host "Sharing     : " $site.SharingCapability

    Write-Host "subsites    : " $site.WebsCount

    Write-Host "-----------------------------------------"

}
```

Here is the link:
https://globaltechstop.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/working-with-sharepoint-site-collections-on-office365-tenant-site-using-pnp-powershell/